Slack is displaying error on button click Error: "Oh no, something went wrong. Please try that again."
  function sendButtonMessage(event, msg, buttons, cb) {
   console.log(buttons);
    const requestBody = {
      "attachments": [
        {
          "text": msg,
          "callback_id": "123",
          "attachment_type": "default",
          "actions": [
              {
                  "name": buttons[0].payload,
                  "text": buttons[0].title,
                  "type": "button",
                  "value": buttons[0].payload,
                  "action_id": "button"
              },
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
        
    console.log("Request body:", JSON.stringify(requestBody));
  
    request(
      {
        uri: `https://hooks.slack.com/services/${$channelId}/B06UB8J1Q0N/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`,
        method: "POST",
        json: requestBody,
      },
      (err, res, body) => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log("send button message:", JSON.stringify(body));
        if (!err) {
          return cb(null, body);
        } else {
          console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
          return cb(null);
        }
      }
    );
  }

While slack integration I'm sending button on slack like above but on click of that button I don't receive any event in AWS cloud watch. I want to receive event to process further.
